# can't read json items with jquery

Tags: jquery, json, html-lists

I've got an unordered list with customer names I get from a JSON file. I want to add a click event, but jQuery can't seem to read it. The list looks good in the HTML source file, but the list items don't show up in the `console.log`. A manual added dummy customer handles the click event just fine.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="customers">
    <li>Dummy customer</li><!-- manually added as a test -->
</ul>
```

**JS (filling up unordered list)**

```
var getCustomers = 'json_webservice_api_I_can't_share';
$.getJSON( getCustomers )
.done(function( data ) {
    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $('#customers').append('<li>' + data[i].Name + '</li>');
    }
});
```

**JS (click event)**

```
$('#customers li').click(function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
}
```

I'm guessing the text inside the list items filled with customer names from the JSON file are no real strings(?). Or something like that. Can somebody help?

Comment: Try to replace console.log to alert

Comment: Try putting click event after for loop in done function

Comment: Without seeing an example of the returned `data` object, it's hard to say much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chances are that you're binding the event when you do not have all the **li** elements


try with

```
$(document).on('click', '#customers li', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

also can be done this way, maybe a better way (see Jan Dvorak comment)

```
$('#customers').on('click', 'li', function() {
    console.log($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: You are awesome. This works! Any thoughts on why this does work and the other click event doesn't?

Comment: @PaulvdDool ajax is asynchronous, your items are created when the call ends, therefore are not created when you bind your click handler

Comment: chances are `#customers` already exists when the handlers are being bound, in which case `$('#customers').on('click', 'li', ...)` would be better.